# How do you test for accelerometer motion while a timer is running?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I'm a casual android developer who is trying to make my application detect multiple shakes of the device.  I want it to start a timer when the first shake is registered and while the timer is running it tests for further shakes.  When the timer is done it will process the number of shakes and output accordingly.  Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager senSensorManager;
private Sensor senAccelerometer;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
private static final int shakeThreshold = 1500;
private long lastUpdate = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this,senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor sensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if((currentTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            long diffTime = (currentTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = currentTime;

            float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z)/diffTime * 10000;

            if(speed > shakeThreshold) {
                //start timer here
            }
            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            last_z = z;
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
/*protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this,senAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}*/
```

}

Comment: Please, include some of the code you have to clarify what is not working on it. And try improving the question being more clear and not so broad. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Here's the code for the project.